# Unclear translation; need help

Tags: translation

A while ago I asked the Galleria Borghese if I was allowed to film there, and they sent me this:

> Gentilissimo, le comunico che sarà possibile scattare fotografie
>   durante la sua visita in Galleria, senza cavalletto e per esclusivo
>   uso personale. Non è altresì possibile filmare le sale e le opere
>   esposte. Rimango a disposizione per eventuali chiarimenti e le auguro
>   un buon soggiorno a Roma. Cordialmente

Now, since I don't speak Italian, I used Google Translate on it, and it gave me this:

> Dear, I inform you that you can take pictures during his visit to the
>   gallery, without a tripod and for personal use only. It is also not
>   possible to film the rooms and the works on display. I am available
>   for any questions and wish you a good stay in Rome. Sincerely

The actual question I asked concerned filming, and I still don't know if that is allowed because of that **"also"**, as the translation gives me no clue about what else is not possible.

Can anyone tell me if I'm allowed to film there or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually says quite explicitly that filming is not allowed. "Altresì" here simply adds this second piece of information: "**In addition** (to what I inform you about), filming of the rooms and art works is not possible." It doesn't mean that there are two things forbidden, it means "I inform you that you can make photos. Also (I inform you), you can't film".

Answer (score 4):

> Non è altresì possibile filmare le sale e le opere esposte

You are not allowed to film.

You can only take pictures, without a tripod, only for personal use.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in having doubts. The original Italian text is bad: it should be

> *È invece vietato filmare le sale e le opere esposte.*

It's wrong to use *altresì* (which is the same as *anche*, but more bureaucratic) for adding something that cannot be done to something that *can*.